# interrogative pronoun where vs. adverb somewhere

Tags: word-meaning

*Tell him where he can put it.*
(Here, *can* means permission.)

Can this sentence be interpreted as *Tell him he can put it somewhere*?

Comment: What do you think "Tell him where your house is" means? It doesn't mean "Tell him your house is somewhere".

Answer (score 0):

> **Tell him where he can put it.**

In that sentence the word **'can'** means **'to be allowed to'** [1](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/can). That sentence doesn't mean **'tell him he can put it somewhere'**. The first sentence is slightly different from the second one. **'Tell him where he can put it'** means **'tell him where he is allowed to put it'**. **'Tell him he can put it somewhere'** means **'tell him he is allowed to put it somewhere'**.